# How to model different superclasses in UML

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have an existing system with People (private), Companies(business) and Employees(business) available. I want to create realations between those entities to define who is an supplier and who is a customer. The next options should be possible:

- A company can be a supplier for a Person as a customer.
- A company can be a supplier for another company as a customer.
- A company can be a supplier for an employee of a company.

There are also products and services available in the existing system. I want to model the following:

- A supplier delivers a product or service to a customer.

And when the product is delivered to the customer, i want to model the following:

- A supplier invoices the delivered product(s) and service(s) to the customer.

How can I model this?

Comment: Could you show us how far you have managed to get trying to model this yourself?

Comment: What exactly do you want to model? There are a lot of different diagrams in the UML.

Comment: I agree with @robjohncox Have you tried to model this? Could you please share it with us?

Comment: So far I have this:https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dcizntiwk6mz0o/Class%20Diagram.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Is supplier need to be an entity ? Maybe it is a role.

What about a solution like that :

[image: Suppliers]

You can make a copy and modify this model with this link : [Clone this model](http://app.genmymodel.com/genmymodel?clonedProject=_I0ytYNK2EDCtk-PK-TnjZA)

Comment: Thanks that looks great (sorry I forgot to comment earlier, but it really helped me:))